# curl_setopt() CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION issue with TCPDF

Tags: php, curl, tcpdf

I have moved one site to another web hosting. When i test on localhost all works fine but when i try it online, i receive the following:

```
curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or 
    an open_basedir is set
```

when i try to generate a PDF file with TCPDF(the line 7542 is generating the error)

```
7534             if ($imsize === FALSE) {
7535                 if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
7536                     // try to get remote file data using cURL
7537                     $cs = curl_init(); // curl session
7538                     curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
7539                     curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
7540                     curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
7541                     curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
7542                     curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

What can i do to avoid this?

Comment: Could you try to comment out open_basedir in you php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

If the hosting company/department isn't willing to turn off safe_mode a workaround might be this useful snippet found at php.net http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php#71313

```
function curl_redir_exec($ch)
{
    static $curl_loops = 0;
    static $curl_max_loops = 20;
    if ($curl_loops++ >= $curl_max_loops) {
        $curl_loops = 0;
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_HEADER => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    list($header, $data) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
        $url = @parse_url(trim(array_pop($matches)));
        if (!$url) {  //couldn't process the url to redirect to
            $curl_loops = 0;
            return $data;
        }
        $last_url = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
        foreach(array('scheme', 'host', 'path') as $component) {
            if (!$url[$component]) {
                $url[$component] = $last_url[$component];
            }
        }
        $new_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] 
                 . ($url['query'] ? '?' . $url['query'] : '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);
        return curl_redir_exec($ch);
    } else {
        $curl_loops = 0;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what's wrong:

> `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set

- [safe_mode<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/safe_mode)
- [open_basedir<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/open_basedir)

You should be able to obtain your current configuration this way:

```
var_dump(array_map('ini_get', array('safe_mode', 'open_basedir')));
```

To remove the error, talk to the support department of your hoster and tell them about your technical requirements for the PHP settings. If the hoster is not able to fullfill your requirements, you've chosen the wrong hoster for your PHP script.

Comment: This does not tell the user how to add curl to his open_basedir settings. As of PHP 5.3 - safe_mode is automatically disabled.

Comment: @JMA: The current stable PHP version 5.4 has it even disabled. And you can not add curl to open_basedir settings AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off `safe_mode` and `open_basedir` in your host. You can ask from hosting support. If it's not available, you can change the value of `open_basedir` to (0).

Example:

```
    curl_setopt($rConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($rConnect, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

should change to

```
    curl_setopt($rConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($rConnect, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```